# Доступ к журналу (Log) SMS в Android

Tags: android-sdk, android, sms, java

Здравствуйте. Знаю, что в SDK есть классы и методы для доступа к журналу звонков в ОС Android. Есть ли такая же возможность для SMS? Т.е. стоит задача: получить список/массив входящих SMS с текстом, номером приславшего, датой-временем и проч. информацией.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,null,null,null);

// column names for above provider:

0: _id 
1: thread_id 
2: address 
3: person 
4: date 
5: protocol 
6: read   
7: status 
8: type 
9: reply_path_present 
10: subject 
11: body 
12: service_center 
13: locked
```

Вместо inbox могут также использоваться другие категории например sent

Comment: Спасибо. Это работает. Это все поля таблицы inbox? Какое поле отвечает за дату/время сообщения? Поле date - это просто какое-то огромное число на каждую запись из БД..

Comment: Не по теме вопроса, просто интересуюсь - для получения подобного рода данных у приложения должны быть настроены какие-то определенные права доступа?

Comment: Разумеется. В файле манифеста нужно прописать следующее 


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

Comment: Все. Кажется, сам разобрался. Большое значение в поле - ничто иное, как тип long, время в миллисекундах (возможно от начала эры Unix - 1970 год, etc.). Методом getLong(4) получаем наше время в миллисекундах и подаем на вход метода format(), класса DateFormat/SimpleDateFormat с нужным шаблоном.


Спасибо, alvin!

Comment: умничка! хотя это и не мне спасибо а какому то чуваку с SOF.com

Answer (score 2):

```
mText.append("\n\n      SMS сообщения");
    mText.append("\n-------------------------------------------------------------");
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    Cursor cur = mainContext.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,null,null,null);
    startManagingCursor(cur);
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy");
    if (cur.getCount() > 0){
        while (cur.moveToNext()){
            mText.append("\n" + format1.format(cur.getLong(4)) + " " + cur.getString(2) + ": " + cur.getString(12) );
            mText.append("\n");
        }
    }
    mText.append("\n########################################");
```

> Знаю, что в SDK есть классы и методы для доступа к журналу звонков в ОС Android

если знаешь можешь помочь? где почитать?

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

LayOut

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Get List Sms"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:onClick="GetSMSList" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Метод получения списке СМС

```
public  void GetSMSList(View v){

        EditText mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mText.append("\n\n      SMS сообщения");
        mText.append("\n-------------------------------------------------------------");
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        Context context=this;
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null,null,null,null);
        startManagingCursor(cur);
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy");
        if (cur.getCount() > 0){
            while (cur.moveToNext()){
                mText.append("\n" + format1.format(cur.getLong(4)) + " " + cur.getString(2) + ": " + cur.getString(12) );
                mText.append("\n");
            }
        }
        mText.append("\n########################################");

    }
```